# How to install Docker on Amazon linux 2023?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, docker-engine, amazon-linux-extras

I am trying to install docker engine on amazon linux 2023 using the docker ce repo with no luck.

i tried to install Docker on amazon linux 2 using the "amazon-linux-extras" but its no longer available on AL2023 even though it was on AL2.

Comment: what is the big-picture goal you are trying to achieve by this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Dsh.

Simple

```
yum install -y docker
```

worked fine for me. I'm using `al2023-ami-2023.0.20230503.0-kernel-6.1-x86_64`

Answer (score 4):

Amazon Linux 2023 uses Fedora as the upstream. So as others suggested `yum install -y docker` can be used.

But also `dnf install -y docker` since dnf is the next-generation yum and running yum actually runs dnf in the background

Comment: This is not an answer. Try commenting on the answer you accepted.